# Error running jest react test, jest not recognized

Tags: npm, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run some jest tests but keep getting the error:

'jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here is my package.json, can anyone please help get my test framework setup?

```
{
 "name": "lac-react",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
 "test": "jest"
},
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "^9.0.8",
  "gulp": "^3.8.11",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
  "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
  "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
  "gulp-streamify": "0.0.5",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
  "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
  "reactify": "^1.1.0",
  "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
  "watchify": "^3.2.1"
},
"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "./preprocessor.js",
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "react"
  ],
  "testPathDirs": [
    "./src/components/__tests__/"
  ]
},
"dependencies": {
  "moment": "^2.10.2",
  "react": "^0.13.2",
  "react-datepicker": "^0.6.2",
  "react-message": "^1.3.0",
  "react-router": "^0.13.3",
  "react-skylight": "^0.2.0",
  "superagent": "^1.2.0",
  "react": "*",
  "react-tools": "*",
  "jest-cli": "*"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closer at the errors, I had this:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, p lease install Visual Studio 2010 build tools.
```

I fixed this with adding the version of the build tools when doing an npm install:

```
--msvs_version=2013
```

All works fine now.

You can also fix this by adding a system variable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install jest-cli. It worked for me.
Just npm i jest-cli
Test script should remain same "jest

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
However it does not read very well as you have not used any formatting, and it's unclear what you mean by *Test script should remain same "jest*